# Как сделать правильное распознавание текста с капчи ВКОНТАКТЕ?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Возник такой вопрос, как на NODE.JS сделать распознавание текста с капчи ВКонтакте. Знаю, что есть модуль Tesseract.js, но безуспешно, он не распознает (распознает, но получается неправильный текст).

Есть вообще какой-либо аналог этому модулю, чтобы можно было получать текст с капч ВК? Или нужно самому писать такие алгоритмы? Если самому писать, то как, и по какому принципу.

Буду благодарен за ответ[image: пример капчи]

Comment: Качаете много капч, распознаёте их вручную, обучаете нейросеть.

Comment: Осваиваете легальный vk-api и не связываетесь с капчей

Comment: Ну так-то капчу для того и придумали, чтобы её программы не распознавали. (А вообще для этого есть специальные платформы, на которых капчи разгадывают люди. Но это конечно же платно.)

Comment: @T0hich71, да знаю... Эх. Значит программно никак не получится?

Comment: Ну возможно нейросеткой, но не думаю что оно того стоит. Да и если вам не нужно писать спамбота (а я надеюсь, что вам не нужно), то используйте нормальный vk api.

Comment: Дело тут совсем не в спам-ботах. Сейчас в последнее время у Bots Long Poll API (группы) возникают частые провалы, то вдруг беседа перестанет события на 2-3 минуты получать (со стороны вк, а страдает именно бот), то ответ очень долгий. Не нравится в принципе такое. А на страничном API (User Long Poll Api) всё гораздо быстрее и без провалов. Не знаю, почему разработчики не исправляют провалы с API сообществ. Жаль.